# Loop through lines in file for input, then output files with unique names?

Tags: bash

I'm using a tool that converts file types, but only works on one file at a time. I've put the URLs to these files into a text file, which I want to loop through with bash. The command then outputs files, but I want each file to be named uniquely. For example, output file one should be named `output1.pdf`, two should be `output2.pdf`, etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in `cat input.txt`; do
    converttopdf $i output.pdf
done
```

But that will simply overwrite output.pdf over and over. How can I make it output a unique file each time?

Comment: `converttopdf $i $i.pdf` so you'd get `test.txt.pdf` as output?

Comment: @Marc: I would, but the URLs are quite long, and I don't want the whole thing to be output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num=0
while read -r; do
    ((num++))
    converttopdf "$REPLY" "output_${num}.pdf"
done < file_with_urls
```

keep a counter, and place in the output filename

Answer (score 0):

With a counter?

```
c=1
echo $c     # "1"
c=$(($c+1))
echo $c     # "2"
```

Comment: Can you explain how I can convert this to a usable file path? Can I just do `converttopdf $i output$c.pdf`? Or is there some way to place the variable inside the argument?